# Another review problem: meh answer to bad, closed, question

Tags: discussion, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6332317

Here we have a shopping question. And, in response, a shopping answer. Yea, it's rather linkful, but what do you expect? Bad questions make bad answers. Better to close and delete the question than to fuss with the answer(s).

Since, in this case, the *question was already closed*, I saw no reason to waste time on the answer. I sighed, copied a link to the question so that I could vote to delete it, and clicked 'looks OK', and ... boom.

It was certainly none of the horrible offensive things that the 'you failed message' described. It might have been a trifle spammy, but it sure wasn't offensive.

Is it really a good idea to audit with answers to closed questions?

Comment: Not answering your question (I would have chosen delete and opened the question and vote for delete). I agree that the main problem is the question and we should focus on get rid of those, most times many of the questions on these would need handling too. Was it a good audit, I can't decide, maybe closed should have been hidden, but all in all in my eyes it's showing stepping into the thread from a review on doubts is a good idea. Sorry for being partial Off Topic.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it can be. In this case, it's pretty obvious that reviewing the answer you linked to was a tedious and pointless thing to do, so I can understand why you didn't want to bother, but that's what the *"skip"* button is for: If you don't know/care/can't be bothered, skip it. Saying it looks OK means that the answer is, all in all, not bad.

The answer in question, though, breaks a few conventions, such as:

- Link-only answers
- Linking to payed service (fishy)
- No explanation as to usage, credibility or accounts of personal experience with the linked tool

In addition to that, you admitted to finding it a bad answer yourself. By clicking *"looks OK"*, you didn't do the job properly.
You should've done either one of two things: vote to delete, or if you really didn't want to bother with that, hit the *"Skip"* button.

## Why?

To answer your question, why do we review answers to a closed (and perhaps soon to be deleted) question?
To me, the reason for this is really quite obvious: A question might be closed, but **it can be re-opened**, for various reasons:

- Invalid close vote
- Duplicate questions *can* yield high quality answers, still. Good enough answers to justify keeping the duplicate (ie: not deleting it)
- Seemingly bad questions can be closed, but in the comments, the OP is chatting away with people who point out to him/her that the question needs to be edited. Meanwhile, an answer or two might get posted, referring to the comments. Some answers might benefit from some reviewing
- In case of closed duplicate questions especially, new users (who didn't know it was a dupe) might have had their first swing at answering. Reviewing a new users' answers is a good thing, still: it enables us to point them in the direction of the help section (what not to ask, what makes an answer a good answer, and how to vote etc...).

Consider the following scenario:

A gold-badge user votes a question as a duplicate. 1k+ means 1 vote to close, but other users find the answers posted to the particular question very informative, or the close-vote was unjustified. A couple of re-open votes are cast, and we go about our lives happily ever after.
Meanwhile, a new user might've posted a low-quality answer, right before the question was closed. New users' posts should always be pushed onto a review queue of sorts, IMO. By leaving out closed questions, some new users might end up posting a low-quality answer that slips under the radar. Getting that feedback to new users, welcoming and pointing out what is expected of them can't do any harm. The only possible effect you can get from it is a slight increase in user awareness a slight improvement in noise to signal ratio (I'm being very optimistic here).

If closed questions can be re-opened, then good quality answers are likely to play a role in the reopening, once a question is reopened, we'd like to have nothing but excellent answers to that question.
Answers by new users that clearly show that they haven't read the help section should be reviewed, and those users should, through a *friendly comment*, be told that what they're doing is not in tune with the format.

Having to hit the *"skip"* button, or deleting a bad answer to a bad question isn't that big of a price to pay, IMHO. Considering we could, potentially, improve the overall quality of both questions and answers. I think we're all agreed that that would be a good thing. As far as I'm concerned, hitting the delete or skip button once or twice is well worth it.
If that's too much of an effort for you, you can always steer clear of the low-quality answer queue...

Comment: This is contrary to the [guidance from Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: @JasonMArcher: How so? I started off by saying the answer, in this particular case, is a bad one. The question here is whether or not reviewing answers to closed questions (as a concept) is useful. The point I tried to make was: _Yes, it can be in case the question was closed for the wrong reason, or enough people deemed the answers too good to loose, and voted to reopen/undelete the question_. TL;TR: Yes, the linked question was bound to get bad answers, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't review answers to closed questions

Comment: I am, in no way, contradicting the guidance you linked to, simply because I'm not telling people _not_ to flag/close bad answers or questions, I'm just trying to explain why I feel reviewing answers to closed questions ***can*** be useful, still

Comment: Per guidance from Shog, that answer should have never been deleted.  Therefore it would not have been selected as an audit and the OP would not have failed.  If the answer is allowable, **Looks OK** is the proper choice.  Now, from a practical perspective it may be a good idea to be aware of these kinds of cases so you don't fall for broken audits.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: Look at what the "answer" links to: it does **not** answer the question. SO is about specific coding problems, the answer links to a commercial service.